# Rake task to destroy records, but not destroying associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

I have a rake task to destroy records of a model older than a certain time. Even though the records are getting deleted, but the associations are not.

The rake task is simple:

```
Product.where("marked = ? AND created_at < ?", false, 15.days.ago).destroy_all
```

The associations:

**Product Model:**

```
has_many :features, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Feature Model:**

```
belongs_to :product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try:

```
@products_to_destroy = Product.where("marked = ? AND created_at < ?", false, 15.days.ago)

@products_to_destroy.destroy_all
```

OR

```
Product.destroy_all("marked = ? AND created_at < ?", false, 15.days.ago)
```

Ref: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Rajesh! Will give it a try and let you know.